# javascript, jQuery running a single function with two different inputs at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys just doing some messing around and learning a few new things to kill time at the moment im fiddling with javascript and i have encountered a problem.

so the problem is that i have downloaded a small jQuery slideshow thing of the internet being simple fade slideshow (i have hacked it to pieces removing stuff i didn't deem necessary) and im trying to get it to run two independent slideshows at the same time.  i want these slideshows to have different dimensions for width and height preferably transition time also and my problem is that the function will only run one slideshow.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({
        width: 300,
        height: 343,
    });
```

is there a way that i can say change `#slideshow` to `#slideshow1` and then have it run on the same bit of code at the same time as `#slideshow`? obviously i could just change some names around and have a ton of text but id prefer to find a neater way.

im fairly novice so any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post a link to the plugin you're using? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: It's probably [this library](https://github.com/pascalbajorat/simplefadeslideshow).

Comment: yep its that library and im using the sample provided so all the stock html and css provided with the plugin

Comment: thanks for all the help guys i'm guessing that the plugin will not support more than one element so ill try fix that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({ width: 300, height: 343 });
     $('#slideshow1').fadeSlideShow({ width: 300, height: 343 });
});
```

Comment: At the same time, might as well use `$('#slideshow, #slideshow1').fadeSlideShow({ width: 300, height: 343, });`

Comment: @Ian: I agree, but the question does state using different dimensions and transition time for each, so this would be the best answer. Except for the trailing commas.

Comment: ok so should it should work if i were to alter the width and height values? because when i implement the differing values the function does not work im using the library mentioned above.

Comment: @Mottie Very true, I just said it because the init options were the same in the question. But I probably shouldn't have mentioned that anyways and just suggested changing the width/height values to show they could be different (even if obvious).

Comment: @user2074307 How much did you modify the original plugin? Are you getting any errors? Honestly, it doesn't look like it's that big (222 lines of code), just minify it if you are that concerned about size.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the plugin works with more than one element:

```
  $('#slideshow', '#slideshow1').fadeSlideShow({
    width: 300,
    height: 343
  });
```

If the plugin is coded for best practices, the above should work.
Looping over an array of selector strings also works in the same manner.

```
  var slideshows = ['#slideshow', '#slideshow1', '#slideshow2'];
  $.each(slideshows, function(el, i) {
    $(el).fadeSlideShow({
      width: 300,
      height: 343
    });
  });
```

Otherwise if the divs are in a logical order, you can programmatically construct the selector.

```
  var slideshowStart = 1;
  var slideshowEnd = 50;
  for(var i = slideshowStart; i <= slideshowEnd; i++) {
    $('#slideshow'+i).fadeSlideShow({
      width: 300,
      height: 343
    });
  }
```

Alternatively, a good lightweight image slideshow plugin is jQuery.cycle. It is well tested and is extremely extensible.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: For your second example, you might as well use `$('#slideshow', '#slideshow1, #slideshow2').each(function () { $(this).fadeSlideShow({ }); });`

Comment: @Ian, true story. My code OCD likes putting things in arrays because they're nicer to format of the list starts becoming unwieldy. I didn't see that OP wanted different settings per element originally.

Answer (score 0):

Since `#slideshow` just denotes a DOM element ID, such as a single div or something, can you not change that to `#slideshow2` and create an additional `div` with an ID of `slideshow2`? If this does not work, then perhaps the slideshow code is written in such a way that this is not possible?